# Gedit launches with Save & Save As disabled unless launched as root

Tags: gedit, gksu

Whether I launch gedit from a terminal or from the GUI, the **Save** and **Save As** menu items are ghosted as soon as gedit opens.  I can't even start with a blank editor, type something, and then **Save As** unless I launched gedit as root.

I first noticed this after an OS upgrade a year or so ago and thought a security setting had changed (or something) and just lived with it.  Lately I've been working on the system a lot more and I realized this is not normal.

Comment: Are you working in your home directory?  This sounds like an incorrect permissions issue.

Comment: Yep.  In my home directory.  I'm user fred, in /home/fred tring to edit anything, for example:  -rw-rw-rw- 1 fred fred    571 Jun  7 19:26 test.txt

Comment: Other apps launched from the terminal seem fine, for example nautilus can delete anything I have write permission for.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You need superuser privileges only to edit files not owned by you, in directories not owned by you. Check the permission on your home directory `ls -ld ~` and check that the `~fred/.gnome2/gedit` directory is yours and you have write rights to it.

Comment: home directory permissions/owner are fine.  Don't have a gedit file or directory under ~fred/.gnome, but permissions/owner seem fine for ~fred/.gnome.  I just noticed that even when I launch gedit from the GUI, Save and Save As are ghosted - before I've typed or opened anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function instead. A function that check the write permission. If write permission is granted don't use `gksu`.

```
function gedit(){ [ -w "$1" ] && gedit "$1" || gksu gedit "$1"; }
```

You can add that in your `.bashrc` instead of the alias.

Comment: That doesn't address the problem, which is that I have to use gksu even when I *have* write permission...

Comment: @FredHamilton It's not a problem, it's because you call `gksu` everytime... And `gksu` need a password, no matter if that, what `gksu` calls, needs root privs or not. You can just minimize the usage of `gksu`. As in my answer described.